# displaying two background images using CSS in IE 6

Tags: html, css

I have a table cell, within that cell I want to display 2 difference background images at 2 separate locations. I am using

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100" height="100">
 <tr>
   <td id="arrow" class="top">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="arrow" class="mid">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td id="arrow" class="bottom">&nbsp;</td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

The css is:

```
td#arrow.top{
    background-image: url('images/pic1.jpg'), url('images/pic2.jpg');
    background-position: left top, center center;
}
```

How can I display 2 separate background images using CSS such that they show up in IE 6.

Comment: IE6 & fancy css, urgh...

Comment: is there a  simple way to have 2 background images in IE 6?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have 2 background images on one element. You'll need to create another element within the cell (which may have the same dimensions as the cell itself) and set one background on each:

```
<td>
    <div class="td-container">
    </div>
</td>

td {
    background: url(/img/bg1.jpg) left top no-repeat;
}
.td-container {
    background: url(/img/bg2.jpg) right bottom no-repeat;
}
```

Alternatively you can create one image which combines both images at the desired locations and put that one as the background.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your images by using divs. It is possible to do try something like

```
<td><div class="top"></div></td>
```

then your css would have

```
top.td
{
background: whatever.jpg;
}
```